# Como recibir texto, archivos por le metodo put en laravel 5.6 (api restFULL)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5, api, http

estoy desarrollando APIS  con laravel 5.6 , tengo un controlador que recibe imagenes y texto ,  por  post todo me fuciona con normalidad aqui dejo el codigo  js

**JS**

```
 function registraPET(){

                var datos = new FormData();
                    jQuery.each(jQuery('.fileExcel')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        datos.append('pet', file);
                    });
                    datos.append('fechaRecepcion','2018-10-10');
                    datos.append('idusuregistropet',1);
                    datos.append('codpetrecibida','asds');
                    datos.append('idcliente',1);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lineatiempopet',
                        type: 'post',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data:datos,
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log(response)
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR,status, errorThrown ){
                            console.log(jqXHR)
                        }
                    });
        }
```

**PHP (LARAVEL  5.6) FUNCION STORE / MÉTODO POST**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       /* $request->validate([
            'fechaRecepcion'=>'required|date',
            'idusuregistropet'=>'required|int',
            'codpetrecibida'=>'required|max:20',
            'fechavisitatecnica'=>'nullable|date',
            'urlpetrecibida'=>'nullable',
            'idusuvistatecnica'=>'nullable|int',
            'idcliente'=>'required|int',
            'observacion'=>'nullable|string|max:300',
            'idcot'=>'nullable|int',
            'fechaEjecucion'=>'nullable|date',
            'urlactaconformidad'=>'nullable|string',
            'urlordenCompra'=>'nullable|string',
            'fechareprogramacion'=>'nullable|date',
            'nrofactura'=>'nullable|string',
            'estado'=>'nullable|string|max1',
        ]);
        if($request->hasFile('pet')){
            $pet = $request->file('pet')->store('/public/documentacionPets/pets');
            $newLienaPET = new LineaTiempoPet();
            $newLienaPET->fechaRecepcion = $request->fechaRecepcion;
            $newLienaPET->idusuregistropet = $request->idusuregistropet;
            $newLienaPET->codpetrecibida = $request->codpetrecibida;
            $newLienaPET->fechavisitatecnica = $request->fechavisitatecnica;
            $newLienaPET->urlpetrecibida = Storage::url($pet);
            $newLienaPET->idusuvistatecnica = $request->idusuvistatecnica;
            $newLienaPET->idcliente = $request->idcliente;
            $newLienaPET->observacion = $request->observacion;
            $newLienaPET->idcot = $request->idcot;
            $newLienaPET->fechaEjecucion = $request->fechaEjecucion;
            $newLienaPET->urlactaconformidad = $request->urlactaconformidad;
            $newLienaPET->urlordenCompra = $request->urlordenCompra;
            $newLienaPET->fechareprogramacion = $request->fechareprogramacion;
            $newLienaPET->nrofactura = $request->nrofactura;
            $newLienaPET->estado = $request->estado;
            $newLienaPET->save();
        }else{
            return response()->json(['data'=>'Debe agregar una  PET','codigo'=>'400'],400);      
        }*/
        $linaTiempoPet = $request -> all(); 


        return response()->json(['data'=>$linaTiempoPet,'codigo'=>'200'],200);

    }
```

El problema es la funcion update / metodo put no llega ningún dato

**JS**

```
Function updatePET(){
            var datos = new FormData();
            jQuery.each(jQuery('.fileExcel')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                        datos.append('pet', file);
                    });
                    datos.append('fechaRecepcion','2018-10-10');
                    datos.append('idusuregistropet',1);
                    datos.append('codpetrecibida','asds');
                    datos.append('idcliente',1);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lineatiempopet/1',
                        type: 'put',
                        cache: false,
                        contentType:false,
                        processData: false,
                        data:datos,
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log(response)
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR,status, errorThrown ){
                            console.log(jqXHR)
                        }
                    });

        }
```

**PHP (LARAVEL  5.6) FUNCION UPDATE / METODO PUT**

```
  public function update(Request $request, LineaTiempoPet $lineatiempopet)
    {   
        //$pet = $request->file('pet')->store('/public/documentacionPets/pets');
        //$lineatiempopet->urlpetrecibida = $pet;
        $as = $request -> all();
        return response()->json(['data'=>$as,'codigo'=>'200'],200);
    }
```

como se pudede ver en controlador estoy retornando todo lo que me manda la vista , esto lo hago para compravar que como llegan los datos, en la funcion store todo llega normal se guarda el archivo y todo va bien pero en la funcion update no llega ningun dato.
GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO A QUIENES ME PUEDAN AYUDAR

Answer (score 0):

me parece que para hacer eso necesita agregar en tu formulario 2 campos "{{ method_field('PUT') }}"(la ruta lo entenrera como PUT) y un "{{ csrf_field() }}"(que no es nada mas que el token si lo usas) y el método para ajax seria "POST" enviando esos dos valores a tu ruta declarada como "resource" debería ir perfecto, espero me haga entender y te sirva de referencia mi comentario. Saludos.